# Execute JavaScript from dynamically created links

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
// video listing
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    var videoid = videos[i].id.videoId;

    //more variables declared .....

    document.getElementById('videos').innerHTML += "<div>"
    + "<a href='#' onclick='showVideo(); return false'>" + videotitle + "</a>" + videodescription + ""
    + "</div>";  

});
```

In `showVideo()` I just trigger an alert and it works, but how can can I pass an argument? for example `videoid` to the function? I tried using

```
+ "<a href='#' onclick='showVideo(" + videoid + "); return false'>" + videotitle + "</a>" + videodescription + ""
```

but I got an error.

Comment: which error? add some description.

Comment: Your example is how you do it. Pass your parameter in parenthesis

Comment: `id` has to start with a letter; otherwise, what error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In showVideo() I just trigger an alert and it works. But how can can I pass an argument for example videoid to the function? I tried using

Really, you need to show more code (or provide the error) in order to diagnose the issue.  It could be anything, but make sure:

- your function received a value
- your `id` is not an integer
- you wrapped your value in a quote string `onclick="func(\""  + "<-- -->" + "\");"`

Example

```js
"use strict";
setup();

// video listing
for (var i = 0, n = videos.length; i < n; i++) {
  var video = videos[i];
  var videoid = video.id.videoId;
  var videotitle = video.title;
  var videodescription = video.description;

  document.getElementById('videos').innerHTML += "<div>" +
    "<a href='#' onclick='showVideo(\"" + videoid + "\"); return false'>" + videotitle + "</a>" +
    videodescription + "" +
    "</div>";

}

function showVideo(videoid) {
  var el = document.getElementById(videoid);
  el.classList.remove('hidden');
}



function setup() {
  // setup
  window.videos = [{
    id: {
      videoId: 'foo'
    },
    title: 'Foo Title: ',
    description: 'All about the foo'
  }, {
    id: {
      videoId: 'bar'
    },
    title: 'Bar Title:',
    description: 'All about the bar'
  }];
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.video {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top:2em;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="videos"></div>
<div id="foo" class="hidden video">foo video</div>
<div id="bar" class="hidden video">bar video</div>
```

Comment: yes, this was it `(\"" + videoid + "\")` instead of `(" + videoid + ")` it works now

Comment: Without quoting it, it would treat your value as a variable, which most likely was `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this line;

```
var videoid = videos[i].id.videoId;
```

It's odd to have an `id` property, and for that to be an object with another ID on it. My guess is you only need

```
var videoid = videos[i].id;
```

Add this line just underneath in dev to make sure you've got an id;

```
if (typeof videoid === 'undefined') { throw new Error('could not find id for video ' + i); }
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not good practice to pass variables to callbacks using inline JS.

Using **jQuery** It will be as simple as `$('#elementId').on('click', callback)`.

Alternatively, with just JS: `document.getElementById('elementId').onclick = callback`.

In both cases, `callback` is defined as `function callback() {...}`

Answer (score -1):

I think you are making mistake on innerHTML binding ... try the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Loops</h2>

<p id="videos"></p>

<script>
var videos = [
{"id":"v1","title":"vedio1", "description":"This is 1st vedio"}, 
{"id":"v2","title":"vedio2", "description":"This is 2st vedio"},
{"id":"v3","title":"vedio3", "description":"This is 3st vedio"},
{"id":"v4","title":"vedio4", "description":"This is 4st vedio"}
];

videos.forEach (function(item, index) {
 document.getElementById('videos').innerHTML += "<div><a href='#' onclick='showVideo(&quot;"+ item.id +"&quot;); return false;'>" + item.title + "</a>" + item.description + "</div>";
});

function showVideo(vedioId){
debugger;
console.log(vedioId);
alert("I am vedio "+vedioId);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FF93TNM1X0SD

Comment: Yes, this was it `(&quot;"+ videoid +"&quot;)` instead of `(" + videoid + ")`. it works now.

Comment: I already added (&quot;"+ videoid +"&quot;) in my example, please check the added link in my post.